# Load data [Into HTML Table] based on selected option in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, html-table, query-builder

**Do not confuse**, **I don't try to change** the information of a **select-option** that is filled from database. I'm trying **to load the data** into a **HTML Table** (in the view blade) based on the selected option from a select, yes the select-option is filled from the database but **I don't want** to delete and **"re-fill"** the select-option data. No, no.

I have seen other examples in Stackoverflow, that it's the reason.

For example, see following tables.

Example 1.

Table **"Cars"**

```
id_cars | manufacturer | car_model  | car_year 
1       | Dodge        | Charger RT | 2012     
2       | Chevrolet    | Camaro ZL1 | 2015     
3       | Mini         | Cooper SS  | 2010     
4       | BMW          | M6         | 2016     
5       | BMW          | M3         | 2016
6       | Ferrari      | 308 GTS    | 1977
7       | BMW          | M1         | 1980
8       | Ford         | Mustang GT | 2015
```

Another table. Table **"Car shop"** (Assuming it's a huge store, it's not real)

```
id_shop | id_car | price  | stock
  1     |   2    | 40000  |  500
  2     |   1    | 50000  |  600
  3     |   4    | 60000  |  300
  4     |   3    | 22000  |  700
  5     |   6    | 32000  |  100
  6     |   8    | 30000  |  200
  7     |   7    | 34000  |  300
  8     |   5    | 45000  |  400
```

Table **"sales"** (Per year, per month x12)

```
id | car_seller       | id_shop | sales_per_month | total_sales_value_per_year | user_car_seller_id
1  | John Williams    |   3     |    2            | 1440000                    |  1
2  | Emily Smith      |   1     |    3            | 1440000                    |  2
3  | Caroline Brown   |   2     |    5            | 3000000                    |  3
4  | Mia Miller       |   4     |    7            | 1848000                    |  4
5  | Mia Miller       |   5     |    6            | 2304000                    |  4
6  | Mia Miller       |   8     |    12           | 6480000                    |  4
7  | Alexander Thomas |   6     |    3            | 1080000                    |  5
7  | Alexander Thomas |   7     |    7            | 2856000                    |  5
```

Now the view. **"car_details.blade.php"**

```xml
<x-app-layout>

  <p class="h5">Sales by model car</p>

  <!--MAYBE COULD WORK WITH A FORM or using JAVASCRIPT, MAYBEE I do not know-->
  <form action="table1">
    @csrf
    <select class="form-control w-full" onchange="fillTable">
      <option value="">Select an option...</option> 
      @foreach ($car_shop as $cars)
        <option>Sales&nbsp;{{ $cars->sales_id }}&nbsp;Cars for sale:{{ $cars->car_name }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </form>
    
  <!--THIS IS THE TABLE-->

  <table class="table table-stripped" id="table1">
    <tr>
      <th>Car Name</th>
      <!--OR MAYBE I NEED TO PUT THE FOLLOWING CODE, 
          BUT I THINK It wouldn't work PROBABLY,
          IT WILL THROW ME AN ERROR SIMILAR TO: property [car_name] does not exit on this collection instance
          I think that could be happen-->
      <td>{{ $cars->car_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Car Year</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Total sales per Month</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Total sales value per Year</th>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</x-app-layout>
```

Finally, the controller **"CarShopController"**

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Cars;
use App\Models\Car_Shop;
use App\Models\Sales;

public function show(Cars $car)
{
    // BUT I wouldn't use the $car variable

    $car_sales = DB::TABLE('car_shop')
        ->JOIN('cars', 'car_shop.id_car', '=', 'cars.id_cars')
        ->JOIN('sales', 'car_shop.id_shop', '=', 'sales.id_shop')
        ->selectRAW("sales.id AS sales_id, CONCAT(cars.manufacturer,' ',cars.model) AS 'car_name', cars.car_year, ")
        ->where('sales.user_car_seller_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    return view('car.car_details', ['car_shop' => $car_sales]);
}
```

**Now I'll explain everything**, that is very similar to my project I didn't put the code of my project because it too long, the controller, the view an the database. Really is too long. Although if I only show a small code snippet it won't be understood

The HTML select-option will show cars that the seller (user logged) has sold.

Then the empty table will show ***full details*** of the sales, made by the seller (user logged).

I have a project with similar function, a select-option with options depending by the user logged, and an empty table that must be filled according to the option chosen.

*The seller wants to see the total sales made in 1 year according to the selected car model.*
**That is my goal**

**I'll explain**, Mia Miller (see table) have 3 sales, the select-option will show only the sales of Mia Miller, then Mia Miller will select the sales of Ferrari 308 GTS and the table ( `<table></table>`)  below will be filled with the data of the selected car.

If Mia Miller select an empty option, the data of the table will be deleted, and it will be empty again. Or if Mia Miller select another car model the data will be replaced.

The function will no redirect to another page, everything work on the same page.

Now, How can I do it? I don't have any idea in my mind, for now. Doing that reminds me of the datatables used in microsoft asp.net.

That is what I am trying but it is in **Laravel and HTML**, I think with javascript could work or maybe with a form could work too. But I think that from the controller something else should be done.

**Important!** Showing all the records and **filtering** the results of the table is not my goal, It's useful but **I don't need** all the records to be shown at once.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form implies a page reload. If you do not want to reload the page, then use javascript. You don't need a form element for the javascript approach. If you have all the data you need already in `$car_shop`, then you can just add `data-*` attributes to your `<option>`s and use them to fill the table below whenever the selected option changes.

```xml
<select id="car-select" class="form-control w-full">
    <option selected disabled>Select an option...</option> 
    @foreach ($car_shop as $cars)
        <option
            data-car-name="{{ $cars->car_name }}"
            data-car-year="{{ $cars->... }}"
            data-car-sales-month="{{ $cars->... }}"
            data-car-sales-year="{{ $cars->... }}">Sales {{ $cars->sales_id }} Cars for sale:{{ $cars->car_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<table class="table table-stripped" id="details-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Car Name</th>
        <td id="car-name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Car Year</th>
        <td id="car-year"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Total sales per Month</th>
        <td id="total-sales-month"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Total sales value per Year</th>
        <td id="total-sales-year"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
const carSelect = document.getElementById("car-select");

const tableCarName = document.getElementById("car-name");
const tableCarYear = document.getElementById("car-year");
const tableTotalSalesMonth = document.getElementById("total-sales-month");
const tableTotalSalesYear = document.getElementById("total-sales-year");

carSelect.addEventListener('change', event => {
    const selectedOption = event.target.selectedOptions[0];

    tableCarName.innerText = selectedOption.dataset.carName;
    tableCarYear.innerText = selectedOption.dataset.carYear;
    tableTotalSalesMonth.innerText = selectedOption.dataset.carSalesMonth;
    tableTotalSalesYear.innerText = selectedOption.dataset.carSalesYear;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Mmmm I got ```undefined``` in ```<td></td>```. What can I do?